# Is Python the best option to load a huge text file to SQL Server?

Tags: java, python, sql-server, csv

I have a few text files in CSV format. Some of them are over 500 MB but less than 1 GB. I need to load each of them to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database as table.

I considered using Python. Is Python a good option (performance-wise) to do things like this? Any Python plugin should be used? I am more of a Java man. How is it compared to Java?

Anyone has the experience? Thanks!

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have the SQL `COPY` command?  And some kind of shell-like command-line interface?  If so (and perhaps even if not) there's no need to involve any programming language at all -- just pipe it in.

Comment: use `SSIS`, SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: `BULK INSERT` would probably work as well.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no scripting language performs as well as native utilities for loading bulk data.

Unless your CSV is malformed and requires pre-scrubbing and transformation, there is no need to limit your choices to programming languages. Use a tool instead. SSIS, BCP, DTS all come to mind for CSV.

If you have need for customized load logic, or client based load, then by all means, Python, Perl, Java, C# can all do it. But it won't load as fast as a tool already built for it (and speed seems to be what you are concerned with).